# The html element turns weird. (dimension of the button element changes to original bootstrap component when included in the index file)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making some php page : file_header.php, file_footer.php, file_index.php, and I load them all in the browser one by one, and the result is fine (as i want). But, the problem appears when i combine file_header.php and file_footer.php in file_index.php.

Here is the problem : there are two buttons in page file_header.php (these are bootstrap button), and i give my custom style to them, i want the buttons looks slim, so i give margin and padding attribute in the css style, and finally i load file_header.php in the browser normally (result is fine / as i want). But, when i combine file_header.php and file_footer.php in file_index.php these two buttons turns into the original bootstrap button (buttons looks fat).

why did it happen ?

```
            <!-- This is file_header.php -->
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <!-- Required meta tags -->
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

                    <title>Hello, world!</title>

                    <style>
                        .navbar{
                            background-color: #563d7c
                        }

                        .btn{
                            margin: 5px;  
                            padding: 2px 50px;
                        }
                    </style>

                </head>
                <body>

                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Login</button>
                                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light active">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                
                </body>
            </html>


            <!-- This is file_footer.php -->
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    
                    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

                    <title>Page Title</title>
                    
                    <style>
                        footer{
                            background-color: #f4f4f4;
                        }
                        .container{
                            padding: 20px;
                        }
                    </style>

                </head>
                <body>

                <footer>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <h5 class="text-muted">Service</h5>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">About Us</a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <h5 class="text-muted">Success Story</h5>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">Let Me See</a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <h5 class="text-muted">Help</h5>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">Terms and Condition</a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>

                </body>
            </html>


            <!-- This is file_index.php -->
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

                </head>
                <body>
                    
                    <?php include 'file_header.php' ?>
                    <div>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                        <h2>My main content is here</h2>
                    </div>
                    <?php include 'file_footer.php' ?>   
                        
                </body>
            </html>
```

I expected the style of every buttons element in the page file_index.php is fine (buttons looks slim / as i want).

OR

I expected the style of every page (file_header, file_footer, file_index) doesn't change at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine the header, main and footer in the index file, you  need to make sure that you have everything just once. Meaning, the doctype, the style, the opening body tag, etc.
So, I'd restructure a little bit your code, your 'file_header' should contain all what's in the `<head>`, I'd create a separate 'file_nav.php' where your navigation code sits, remove all the wrapping content from the 'file_footer' and leave there only the footer code.
Somehow like this:

```
<!-- This is file_header.php -->
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <style>
        .navbar{
            background-color: #563d7c
        }

        .btn{
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 2px 50px;
        }

        footer{
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        .container{
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<!-- This is file_nav.php -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Login</button>
                <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light active">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- This is file_footer.php -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h5 class="text-muted">Service</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">About Us</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h5 class="text-muted">Success Story</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">Let Me See</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h5 class="text-muted">Help</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <p><a href="#" class="text-muted">Terms and Condition</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- This is file_index.php -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<?php include 'file_header.php' ?>
    <body>
        <?php include 'file_nav.php' ?>
        <div>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
            <h2>My main content is here</h2>
        </div>
        <?php include 'file_footer.php' ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help :) it works, i didn't know before

Answer (score 0):

Your `file_header.php` and `file_footer.php` are entire HTML page structures. They should be partials of just the HTML markup you want to include in the place they are PHP "include"ed.

An example of `file_header.php` without the doctype, head, html tag, or body:

```
                <style>
                    .navbar{
                        background-color: #563d7c
                    }

                    .btn{
                        margin: 5px;  
                        padding: 2px 50px;
                    }
                </style>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Login</button>
                                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light active">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

The reason your styles are being overridden when `file_footer.php` is included is because you are again for the second time including the bootstrap CSS in a `<link />` tag. Part of the cascading in CSS is that the last declared rule takes priority and so the second inclusion overrides your custom styles.

You should include your bootstrap `<link />` tag in your `file_index.php` head only.